# Use getInitialProps in Layout component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I have this layout component located in `layouts` folder in which getInitialProps is not accessible. What I'm trying to do is use the `getInitialProps` in my layout component. I already read some post that I need to put the layout component enclosed in the `_app.js` file which I don't want all of my pages to access that layout.

```html
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class WithUserLayout extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    console.log('layout')
  }
  render() {
    const {children} = this.props
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {children}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

WithUserLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node
  ])
}
export default WithUserLayout
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: As you have said in your question, `getInitialProps` is only available for page components. You need to first fetch the data in those components and pass down as props to your `<Layout>` component

Comment: Actually, what I want is to fetch an api in the layout since there are data that I need in the page component from the layout component.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my bad in the comments. Yes, HOCs would be a lovely way to approach this. `getInitialProps` is only available to page components, providing that there's no HOC wrapped outside that component. Now that you had an HOC, `getInitialProps` would be available to it, but now not your actual page component! Therefore, you have to manually invoke that method from this HOC, and would look like so:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const withUserLayout = (child: Child) => {
  return class WithUserLayout extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      let pageProps = {};
      try {
        if (Child.getInitialProps) {
          pageProps = await Child.getInitialProps(ctx);
        } 
      } catch (err) {
       throw new Error(`Cannot invoke getInitalProps of ${Child.displayName}`, err.stack);
      }

      return pageProps;
    }

    render() {
      // Rendering
    }
  }
}
```

For further reference please have a look at this [useful code snippet](https://gist.github.com/dstreet/7642b229e33f3cfe137dd7f3bae7a37d)

Comment: Thanks for this Brian, I'll let you know if this catch the scenario that I want.

Comment: Lemme know if there are any problems